# Pyinstaller gives an error KeyError: 'CALL_FUNCTION'

Tags: python-3.x, compiler-errors, pyinstaller

when i try to compile my code i get this error
i have wheel module and all necessary modules
with the code itself, everything is also in order, I tried to compile other programs and had the same error, I did not find anything about this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 107, in run
    parser = generate_parser()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 78, in generate_parser
    import PyInstaller.building.build_main
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 35, in <module>
    from PyInstaller.depend import bindepend
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 26, in <module>
    from PyInstaller.depend import dylib, utils
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\utils.py", line 33, in <module>
    from PyInstaller.depend import bytecode
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bytecode.py", line 95, in <module>
    _call_function_bytecode = bytecode_regex(rb"""
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bytecode.py", line 60, in bytecode_regex
    pattern = re.sub(
              ^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\re\__init__.py", line 185, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bytecode.py", line 62, in <lambda>
    lambda m: _instruction_to_regex(m[1].decode()),
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bytecode.py", line 40, in _instruction_to_regex
    return re.escape(bytes([dis.opmap[x]]))
                            ~~~~~~~~~^^^
KeyError: 'CALL_FUNCTION'
```

Comment: create a [example]

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Updating pyinstaller to latest version, pyinstaller-5.11.0 worked for me

```
pip install -U pyinstaller
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the same thing here, and it appears to be related to the use of Python 3.11 (which is pre-release). Using 3.10 avoids this issue.

Comment: You should be more precise, and add the documentation if you can, or add where to find a guide on how to update it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).